# Changing model value inside directive

Tags: angularjs

I have a tag  inside a directive, click on this anchor should change state of the directive's model variable and refresh the directive view that depends on this scope variable. There are two way to achieve this in Angular:

1)

`<my-directive>`
    `<a ng-click="myProperty = 'foo'">bar</a>`
   `</my-directive>`

Inside the directive controller:

```
$scope.$watch('myProperty', function(value) {
  myPromise.then(function() { //the promise exists in real code but does not have anything to do with the question itself
    updateComponent(value);
  });
});
```

2)

`<my-directive>`
    `<a ng-click="handleMyPropertyChange('foo')">bar</a>`
  `</my-directive>`

Inside the directive controller:

```
$scope.handlePropertyChange = function(value) {
   $scope.myProperty = value;
   myPromise.then(function() {
       updateComponent(value);
   });
});
```

Which one is preferred and why?

Comment: I would go with the second, though cant tell why :P. as such there is no difference between the two. may be just to avoid adding another $watch

Answer (score 0):

I prefer the second option. Code belongs in the controller and even a simple assignment is still code.